# The best way to achieve a find in ember js and not lose the current controller scope

Tags: ember.js

I want to do an ember js find based on an id.

If an object with that id exists I would like to perform some logic on that object.

So, I do so based on the following code:

```
Cluey.UsersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  keypadNum: "",
  loginWithPin: function() {
    var res;
    console.log("Login with pin: " + this.get('loginPin'));
    res = Cluey.User.find({
      pin: this.get('loginPin')
    });
    return res.on('didLoad', function() {
      var user;
      if (res.get('firstObject') != null) {
        user = res.objectAt(0);
        return this.doLogin(user);
      } else {
        return alert("User not found with pin " + this.get('loginPin'));
      }
    });
  },
  doLogin: function(user) {
    //some code
  }
});
```

The problem is that once I am in the res.on('didLoad') callback, I lose the scope of the controller, and therefore when I try to access this.get("loginPin"), it is returned as undefined.

Does anyone know how to solve this.

thanks!

Comment: hmm, does extracting the callback code into a function in the controller and calling `res.on('didLoad', this, 'function_name');` help? (i'm not quite sure if you'll have access to `res` then - or if you have access to it right now for that matter.)

Comment: I don't think I will have access to res if I call a method in the controller. I do have access to it as it stands now, I just don't have access to anything in the controller ie: this.get('loginPin')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass an object as the second parameter in the `on` event, it will be your context in the callback.

You can pass `this` as the second parameter for the `didLoad` event:

```
res.on('didLoad', this, function() {
  var user;
  if (res.get('firstObject') != null) {
    user = res.objectAt(0);
    return this.doLogin(user);
  } else {
    return alert("User not found with pin " + this.get('loginPin'));
  }
});
```

Comment: Worked a charm! Thanks Teddy

Answer (score 0):

You could create a var called `self` and assign `this` to it.

```
Cluey.UsersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  keypadNum: "",
  var self = this;
  loginWithPin: function() {
    var res;
    console.log("Login with pin: " + this.get('loginPin'));
    res = Cluey.User.find({
      pin: self.get('loginPin')
    });
    return res.on('didLoad', function() {
      var user;
      if (res.get('firstObject') != null) {
        user = res.objectAt(0);
        return this.doLogin(user);
      } else {
        return alert("User not found with pin " + this.get('loginPin'));
      }
    });
  },
  doLogin: function(user) {
    //some code
  }
});
```

Comment: Where is "self" used there? Shouldn't you replace "this" with "self" in the closures, if the object is to propagate the current value of "this" into the closures?